# Drawing text in a pieChart drawRect method?

Tags: ios, pie-chart

okie i am using a PieChart i got from github [Astrokin Piechart](https://github.com/astrokin/PieChart)

But in this piechart label has not been added to different slices and i want something as shown below
[image: Pie chart view]

I have looked up on stackoverflow already and am trying to draw text in draw rect but doesnt seem to work. code is below

```
for (int i = 0; i < slicesCount; i++)
   {


double value = [self.datasource pieChartView:self valueForSliceAtIndex:i];

   NSString *title = [self.datasource pieChartView:self titleForSliceAtIndex:i];

   endAngle = startAngle + M_PI*2*value/sum;

   /*CGFloat x = centerX + (radius+10) * (cos((startAngle-90)*M_PI/180.0) + cos((endAngle-90)*M_PI/180.0)) / 2;
   CGFloat y = centerY + (radius+10) * (sin((startAngle-90)*M_PI/180.0) + sin((endAngle-90)*M_PI/180.0)) / 2;

   [title drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(x, y) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_HELVETICA size:12.0]];*/

   CGFloat x =  centerX + ((radius + 10) * cos(startAngle));
   CGFloat y = centerY + ((radius + 10) * sin(endAngle));

  // NSLog(@"X Y: %f %f %f", x, y, degree);

   NSString *text = @"Test";
   [text drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 44) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];

   CGContextAddArc(context, centerX, centerY, radius, startAngle, endAngle, false);

   UIColor  *drawColor = [self.datasource pieChartView:self colorForSliceAtIndex:i];

   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, drawColor.CGColor);
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
   CGContextStrokePath(context);
   startAngle += M_PI*2*value/sum;

}
```

right now it looks like this

[image]

What am i possibly doing wrong?

Comment: In which way does it not work? Doesn't draw at all? Draws bad? Give some examples.

Comment: added image of what it seems like currently

Comment: Looks like the top left corner of your text is in the right position, so using `[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(x - 25, y - 44, 50, 44) ...` instead might work.

Answer (score 0):

You draw text with

```
[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 44) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
```

That makes your text's top left corner to appear at point (x,y). As I can see, you want text's center to appear at point (x,y). What you need to do is to subtract half of the text's width from x and the same for y, so that it becomes:

```
CGFloat height = 50.0;
CGFloat width = 44.0;
[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(x - width / 2.0, y - height / 2.0, width, height) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]];
```

Also you'll need to dynamically get text's width based on the string you have, "95%" is wider than "5%", yeah? So you'll need something like:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithFont:font]; // -sizeWithFont is deprecated in iOS7, you'll need something else
CGFloat height = textSize.height;
CGFloat width = textSize.width;
[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(x - width / 2.0, y - height / 2.0, width, height) withFont:font];
```